# Get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: jquery, ssl

My site is HTTPS and I have a button to play audio from external web radio. I used this code to insert the audio:

```
<audio preload="none" src="http://stream.radio.com/mo2"></audio>
```

However it doesn't work. In Chrome console et get this error

```
GET https://stream.radio.com/mo2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

You notice that the `http` has been transformed to `https`. How can I force the use of `http` instead of `https` in my `src`?

Comment: You cannot access insecure content (ie. `http://`) from a secure one, so that part of your question is not possible. If you're getting 'connection refused' then you most likely are not allowed to access the content from your domain, or you've not authenticated the request properly. Note that my test gets a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error instead, which implies the URL you're using for the audio is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rL0a8g71/

Comment: Sorry, this is the url of the radio : [link] http://stream.midlar.fo/ras2 [/link] the site does not work by replace http with https

Comment: That's still an invalid URL:http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/saobur3f/. You can test it yourself simply by putting it in your browser

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `video` tag with `source`.

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
  <source src="http://stream.midlar.fo/ras2" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
```

Running the above snippet with HTTPS, you will get the error `GET https://stream.midlar.fo/ras2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. But, if you try it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL23h5bs/) with HTTP, it will work.

Comment: My site is HTTPS, so I can't play the source on my site ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, I have followed your advice.

Comment: @goodstuff no, as this source does not support https:// and your site cannot contain insecure content.